# Stopping movement of SCNPhysicsBody

Tags: ios, scenekit

I use gesture listeners and applyForce (with impulse) for moving an object.
How can I stop the movement when the gesture is finished?

I coult apply a force in the opposite direction, but how do I get the magnitude? Or could I use the friction or the velocity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func handlePinch(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        self.cameraNode1.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
        return
    }
```